# Forcing a lower case i for all instances of iPad or iPhone on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im stumped. Im trying to work out how I can use javascript to find all instances of 'ipad' or 'iphone' on a page and then force each one to use a lowercase 'i' so they appear iPad or iPAD?

Comment: Try a `regex` and `.replace()`, that would be a start.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a regex that first checks for the letter `i`, then checks that the letter `i` is followed by either `phone` or `pad`:

```
var appleRegex = /i(?=(phone)|(pad))/gim;
```

You can then use `replace()` to replace any `i` character that matches this regex with a lowercase `i`:

```
var theText = 'IPAD and IPHONE';
var replacedText = theText.replace(appleRegex, 'i');
```

In the above, `theText` is the string you want to check against, and `replacedText` is the same string after both words are made to use a lowercase i.

I've created a fiddle demonstrating this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/LLukhy1L/).

**EDIT**

To alter HTML content, you'll need to set up `theText` in the example to equal the contents of the HTML you wish to replace:

```
var theText = document.getElementById('{YOURID}').innerHTML;
```

Then you would need to update the element after replacing the text:

```
document.getElementById('{YOURID}').innerHTML = replacedText;
```

I've updated the Fiddle to showcase this, and the update can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/LLukhy1L/2/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand how this works, however how would I apply it to my site so that it replaces each instance in the page correctly?

http://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/LLukhy1L/

Comment: That depends, are you triyng to replace `HTML` text? In that case, you would need to set up `theText` in the example to equal the contents of the HTML you wish to replace, with something like `var theText = document.getElementById('{YOURID}').innerHTML;` where {YOURID} is equal to the element ID containing the text. Then you would need to set it after replacing it, with something like: `document.getElementById('{YOURID}').innerHTML = replacedText`. I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: My answer has been updated, and you can see it in action over at http://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/LLukhy1L/2/ :)